# Debug error when removing protection from a workbook opened in a new window

Tags: excel, vba

I have a work book that imports data from workbooks created from web sites. When the web sites create the workbooks they are automatically opened in a new window and the names of the workbooks always change. I use

```
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
```

One of the workbooks has to be opened in protected view so I use

```
Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit
```

to allow it to be edited before import

I can step through the macro and it works but when I run it I always get "Run-time error '91': Object Variable or with block variable not set. I hit debug and play and the program finishes with out a problem.

The complete code looks like this;

```
Sub Data()
Dim Here As String
Dim What As String
Dim Data As String
Dim DropIt As String
Dim StartBook As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

StartBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name

DropIt = "Data1"
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit 'THIS IS WHERE THE DEBUG HAPPENS

Range("A1").Select
Here = ActiveSheet.Name
BookName = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    Rows("1:3").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range("A1").Select
What = Range("A1", ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Address
Data = Range("A2", ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Address

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Here).Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Here).Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("A1") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Here).Sort
        .SetRange Range(What)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    Range(Data).Copy

    Workbooks(StartBook).Activate
    Worksheets(DropIt).Select
    Range("a10").Select
    ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select

    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.End(xlToRight)).Select

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False        

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        Workbooks(BookName).Close savechanges:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I just want the code to run without the Debug

''''

Answer (score 0):

I can't test, but I'll make an untested suggestion. Try changing:

```
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit
```

to:

```
Dim someWorkbook as Workbook
Set someWorkbook = Application.ProtectedViewWindows(1).Edit
```

I think there are other potential problems with your code.

---

Errors that "disappear" when you're debugging/manually stepping through the code usually indicate that your code expected something to be active at runtime but it was (for whatever reason) not active (hence the error) -- and now that you're stepping through it line by line, the object is active and you no longer get an error. This is not always the case, but I think it's a possibility.

I am not familiar with `ActiveProtectedViewWindow`, but I would suggest you instead access/refer to the `ProtectedViewWindow` in a more robust manner (which does not rely on the `ProtectedViewWindow` being active).

If you're certain there will only be 1 protected window, you could try something like `Application.ProtectedViewWindows(1).Edit`. If you have multiple `ProtectedViewWindows` and you only want a particular one, maybe you could loop through all `ProtectedViewWindows` and check if their `SourcePath` property matches the path of the protected workbook that you want to enable editing within.

From what I've read online, `ProtectedViewWindow.Edit` returns a workbook, so you can set a `Workbook` reference to it there and then (as shown at the start of my answer).

I haven't tested the below, but I think your code can be re-written something like it. I recommend saving copies of workbooks/files before running it (or step through it with `F8` key):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Data()
    Dim startWorkbook As Workbook ' Do you have better name for this variable?
    Set startWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook ' Can you refer to this workbook by name, instead of assuming it will be active? Using ThisWorkbook is an option too, as long as you're storing the code in startWorkbook

    Dim unprotectedWorkbook As Workbook ' This needs a better variable name.
    Set unprotectedWorkbook = Application.ProtectedViewWindows(1).Edit ' I don't know if this will work for you (in your case), but I've taken it from Microsoft's documentation

    Dim someWorksheet As Worksheet
    someWorksheet = unprotectedWorkbook.Worksheets(1) ' If you know the worksheet's name, refer to it by name, please.

    With someWorksheet
        .Rows("1:3").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        .Rows("2:2").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        .Columns("E:E").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        .Columns("C:C").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        .Columns("A:A").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

        ' xlCellTypeLastCell isn't always the best way to get the last cell.
        Dim someRangeIncludingHeaders As Range ' This needs a better name.
        Set someRangeIncludingHeaders = .Range("A1", .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))

        Dim someRange As Range ' This needs a better name.
        Set someRange = .Range("A2", .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))

        With .Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=.Range("A1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange someRangeIncludingHeaders
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End With

    someRange.Copy
    startWorkbook.Worksheets("Data1").Range("A10").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    unprotectedWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

The main changes I made were:

- ActiveSheet is not used, so the code should run the same (irrespective of what sheet happens to be active).
- Object references are `set` for workbooks, worksheets, ranges.
- Instead of using `Select` or `Selection`, we refer to the range by its address explicitly.
- The `With` statement block is mainly for convenience. Every object that starts with a `.` inside the `With` block is a member of the object after the `With` keyword (which in this case is `someWorksheet`).